# is there a Base64-based dist?

Tags: linux, bsd, unix-philosophy, base64

Is there a Linux distribution or Unix version where everything is Base64 encoded in memory? I'm interested in the concept of being able to dump the entire system state and print it as a book.

Comment: Are you suffering from insomnia? :-)

Answer (score 7):

No. I don't think there are any processors that can deal with Base64-encoded data, and that'd be a pretty hard requirement for storing data that way in RAM (at least as far as Linux is concerned).

If you want to do this, some virtual machine hypervisors can suspend & save the state of a VM. You could then base64 encode that. Would be a pretty long book, though!

(Quick experiment: I get around 4KiB/page of Base64. Rather fitting to get one page per page. So a 512-page book gets you 2MiB. A full RAM image is going to be a lot of volumes. There are probably more efficient encodings, e.g., some 2D barcode)